# Accessing class members in a delegate in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to create a class whose frame update method can be defined by a delegate; however, I've found that a delegate cannot access its class's members. Is there any way to do this? Is there an alternate method anyone can suggest to have a dynamically defined method like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the parent instance reference to the delegate as a parameter, i.e.

```
class Parent : IParent
{
    readonly Func<IParent, IFrame> _render;
    public IFrame Render()
    {
         return _render(this);
    }
}
```

Of course, unless the render delegate is also a part of the class or its internal classes, it will only be able to access public members.

Note that it's a good idea to use an interface as the parameter type, and to choose a minimum interface which is needed by the delegate (and expose nothing more), as this will allow you greater extensibility.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Dunno why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: @Groo Thank you for your answer, but something still make me unsure. It is possible/appropriate use for this purpose Closure?

Comment: @viceriel: you're right, that would be a fine approach too. So for the example above you could have a `Func<IFrame>` delegate which just captures the parent instance. The approach where you're passing the instance as a parameter allows the render method theoretically to be stateless, but both approaches are fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make an interface which you can pass as a parameter for the delegate, then implement the interface with the class you are passing the delegate to, and pass the instance when you are invoking the delegate.